# Split Multiple Value Types in Same Column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Detail <- c('Name', 'Value', 'Value', 'Name', 'Value', 'Value', 'Value', 'Name', 'Value')
Value <- c('Jim', 100, 200, 'Sally', 300, 200, 300, 'Jim', 500)

df <- data.frame(ID, Detail, Value)
```

The problem here is that for each record `ID`, the `Value` has names and values.  I need to reshape the `Value` column so that the names go into own column and values into their own.

Desired output looks like this.

I'm not even sure where to start...or what to search for.

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3)
Name <- c('Jim', 'Jim', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Jim')
Value <- c(100,200,300,200,300,500)

want <- data.frame(ID, Name, Value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest approach would be like this:

```
dfNames=df[Detail=="Name",-2]
dfValue=df[Detail=="Value",-2]


dfWide=merge(dfNames,dfValue,by="ID")
colnames(dfWide)=c("ID","Name","Value")


  ID  Name Value
1  1   Jim   100
2  1   Jim   200
3  2 Sally   300
4  2 Sally   200
5  2 Sally   300
6  3   Jim   500
```

Comment: Sigh...I'm actually embarassed that  I didn't think of this approach.  I've got to benchmark this against the `dplyr` approaches, as my dataset is quite large.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can deal with your problem in several ways, I'll show one of `dplyr` approaches:

```
library('dplyr')

inner_join(filter(df, Detail == 'Name'),
           filter(df, Detail == 'Value'),
           by = 'ID') %>% 
  select_at(vars(-contains('Detail'))) %>% 
  setNames(c('ID', 'Name', 'Value'))
```

> ```
>   ID  Name Value
> 1  1   Jim   100
> 2  1   Jim   200
> 3  2 Sally   300
> 4  2 Sally   200
> 5  2 Sally   300
> 6  3   Jim   500
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dplyr`, assuming you have only one Name for each `ID`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% do({
    data.frame(Name = .$Value[.$Detail == "Name"], Value = .$Value[.$Detail == "Value"])
})

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID   Name  Value
#  <dbl> <fctr> <fctr>
#1     1    Jim    100
#2     1    Jim    200
#3     2  Sally    300
#4     2  Sally    200
#5     2  Sally    300
#6     3    Jim    500
```

---

Use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Name = Value[Detail == "Name"], Value = Value[Detail == "Value"]) ,ID]

#   ID  Name Value
#1:  1   Jim   100
#2:  1   Jim   200
#3:  2 Sally   300
#4:  2 Sally   200
#5:  2 Sally   300
#6:  3   Jim   500
```